# Unexpected compilation diagnostic when compiling with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a solution which uses C#8 nullable reference types and has `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in a csproj property group. Everything compiles in VisualStudio and on the command line without warnings or errors.

However, when I load the same solution using Roslyn with MSBuildWorkspace, I see dozens of the following project-level diagnostic:

> error CS8632: The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.

I would not expect to see this error because the same solution compiles without warnings/errors in Visual Studio (which respects the csproj setting that enables `#nullable`).

What would cause Roslyn to ignore the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the csproj?

Comment: Have you set it in [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: Which version of the Roslyn packages are you using?

Comment: @stuartd no it is set in each .csproj file. Is that a problem?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I'm using version 3.8.0 of the Roslyn packages and Microsoft.Build.Locator 1.2.6.

Comment: I had this even with VS2022, new net6 project (with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`) added to old solution with other projects (no use of c#8 nullable reftypes). The warning appeared only under the question mark in the code window, not in Error List. Deleting the old _bin_ and _obj_ directories, as recommended in MS migration guide, made the warning in the code window disappear.